# Pyspark - Select users seen on at least 2 consecutive days

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `dataframe_actions` with the fields: `user_id`, `action`, `day`. The `user_id` is unique to each user and the `day` takes values from 1 to 31. I want to filter out only the users seen for at least 2 consecutive days, for example:

If a user is seen on days 1,2,4,8,9, I want to keep them, since they are seen in at least 2 consecutive days.

What I am doing now is clunky and really slow (and does not seem to work):

```
df_final = spark.sql(""" with t1( select user_id, day, row_number()
           over(partition by user_id order by day)-day diff from dataframe_actions), 
           t2( select user_id, day, collect_set(diff) over(partition by user_id) diff2 from t1) 
           select user_id, day from t2 where size(diff2) > 2""")
```

Something along these lines, but I don't know how to really fix this.

**EDIT:**

```
| user_id | action | day |
--------------------------
| asdc24  | conn   |  1  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  2  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  5  |
| adsfa6  | conn   |  1  |
| adsfa6  | conn   |  3  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  9  |
| adsfa6  | conn   |  5  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  11 |
| adsfa6  | conn   |  10 |
| asdc24  | conn   |  15 |
```

should return

```
| user_id | action | day |
--------------------------
| asdc24  | conn   |  1  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  2  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  5  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  9  |
| asdc24  | conn   |  11 |
| asdc24  | conn   |  15 |
```

since only this user was connected for a minimum of two consecutive days (days 1 and 2).

Comment: can you provide the sample input for 2 different users along with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag` to get the previous day for each user, subtract it from the current row's day and then check to see if atleast one of them is 1. This is done with `group by` and a `filter` thereafter.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy(dataframe_actions.user_id).orderBy(dataframe_actions.day)
user_prev = dataframe_actions.withColumn('prev_day_diff',dataframe_actions.day-f.lag(dataframe_actions.day).over(w))
res = user_prev.groupBy(user_prev.user_id).agg(f.sum(f.when(user_prev.prev_day_diff==1,1).otherwise(0)).alias('diff_1'))
res.filter(res.diff_1 >= 1).show()
```

One more way with a difference of row numbers approach. This will enable the selection of all columns for a given user_id.

```
w = Window.partitionBy(dataframe_actions.user_id).orderBy(dataframe_actions.day)
rownum_diff = dataframe_actions.withColumn('rdiff',day-f.row_number().over(w))
w1 = Window.partitionBy(rownum_diff.user_id)
counts_per_user = rownum_diff.withColumn('cnt',f.sum(f.when(rownum_diff.rdiff == 1,1).otherwise(0)).over(w1))
cols_to_select = ['user_id','action','day']
counts_per_user.filter(counts_per_user.cnt >= 1).select(*cols_to_select).show()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'day' is not defined. Don't see where the issue is.

Comment: fixed it..was missing an alias

Comment: seems to still have two issues: first, .alias('diff_1'))) in the last row I think closes too many brackets. I changed that , but now it says: NameError: name 'up' is not defined

Comment: copy-pasted it : 

    user_prev.groupBy(user_prev.user_id).agg(sum(f.when(user_prev.prev_day_diff==1,1).otherwise(0)).alias('diff_1'))).filter(user_prev.diff_1 >= 1).show()
                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax in the same place, where you close 3 brackets , before the last filter operation.

Comment: Ran latest edit : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'diff_1'

Comment: NameError: name 'diff_1' is not defined

Comment: WORKS ! So I get a dataframe with user_id and diff1, these user_ids correspond only to users seen for AT LEAST 2 consecutive days?

Answer (score 2):

Another SQL approach using the given inputs.

**Pyspark**

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> df = sc.parallelize([("asdc24","conn",1),
... ("asdc24","conn",2),
... ("asdc24","conn",5),
... ("adsfa6","conn",1),
... ("adsfa6","conn",3),
... ("asdc24","conn",9),
... ("adsfa6","conn",5),
... ("asdc24","conn",11),
... ("adsfa6","conn",10),
... ("asdc24","conn",15)]).toDF(["user_id","action","day"])
>>> df.createOrReplaceTempView("qubix")
>>> spark.sql(" select * from qubix order by user_id, day").show()
+-------+------+---+
|user_id|action|day|
+-------+------+---+
| adsfa6|  conn|  1|
| adsfa6|  conn|  3|
| adsfa6|  conn|  5|
| adsfa6|  conn| 10|
| asdc24|  conn|  1|
| asdc24|  conn|  2|
| asdc24|  conn|  5|
| asdc24|  conn|  9|
| asdc24|  conn| 11|
| asdc24|  conn| 15|
+-------+------+---+

>>> spark.sql(""" with t1 (select user_id,action, day,lead(day) over(partition by user_id order by day) ld from qubix), t2 (select user_id from t1 where ld-t1.day=1 ) select * from qubix where user_id in (select user_id from t2) """).show()
+-------+------+---+
|user_id|action|day|
+-------+------+---+
| asdc24|  conn|  1|
| asdc24|  conn|  2|
| asdc24|  conn|  5|
| asdc24|  conn|  9|
| asdc24|  conn| 11|
| asdc24|  conn| 15|
+-------+------+---+

>>>
```

**Scala version**

```
scala> val df = Seq(("asdc24","conn",1),
     | ("asdc24","conn",2),
     | ("asdc24","conn",5),
     | ("adsfa6","conn",1),
     | ("adsfa6","conn",3),
     | ("asdc24","conn",9),
     | ("adsfa6","conn",5),
     | ("asdc24","conn",11),
     | ("adsfa6","conn",10),
     | ("asdc24","conn",15)).toDF("user_id","action","day")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [user_id: string, action: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.orderBy('user_id,'day).show(false)
+-------+------+---+
|user_id|action|day|
+-------+------+---+
|adsfa6 |conn  |1  |
|adsfa6 |conn  |3  |
|adsfa6 |conn  |5  |
|adsfa6 |conn  |10 |
|asdc24 |conn  |1  |
|asdc24 |conn  |2  |
|asdc24 |conn  |5  |
|asdc24 |conn  |9  |
|asdc24 |conn  |11 |
|asdc24 |conn  |15 |
+-------+------+---+


scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("qubix")

scala> spark.sql(""" with t1 (select user_id,action, day,lead(day) over(partition by user_id order by day) ld from qubix), t2 (select user_id fro
m t1 where ld-t1.day=1 ) select * from qubix where user_id in (select user_id from t2) """).show(false)
+-------+------+---+
|user_id|action|day|
+-------+------+---+
|asdc24 |conn  |1  |
|asdc24 |conn  |2  |
|asdc24 |conn  |5  |
|asdc24 |conn  |9  |
|asdc24 |conn  |11 |
|asdc24 |conn  |15 |
+-------+------+---+


scala>
```